# Starting activity with an intent in a Worker does not work on some devices

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager, worker

I am trying to implement a `Worker` using `WorkManager` API to open an activity only once on a specific time/date when the app is in background, It does work in my emulator even on Android 12 but when I run it on my Redmi note 8 phone it does not open the activity although the workers are working normally on the same phone
**OpenActivityWorker.kt**

```kotlin
class OpenActivityWorker(val context: Context, private val workerParameters: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, workerParameters) {
    @OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(Runnable {
            val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            val res = context.startActivity(intent)
            Log.d("OpenActivityWorker", "doWork: $res")
        })
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

And I register the worker as follows:

```kotlin
val oneTimeWorkRequestActivity = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(OpenActivityWorker::class.java)
            .setInitialDelay(SOME_MILLIS,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
            )
            .setInputData(
                Data.Builder()
                    .putLong("startAt", SOME_MILLIS)
                    .putLong("id", SOME_ID)
                    .build()
            )
            .build()

WorkManager.getInstance(requireContext()).enqueueUniqueWork(
            "$SOME_ID",
            ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
            oneTimeWorkRequestActivity
        )
```

How to solve this, and is there some kind of permission I need to ask for to be able to start the activities from `WorkManager`?

Answer (score 0):

In your first code block, when do you call this line?

```
class OpenActivityWorker(val context: Context, private val workerParameters: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, workerParameters) {
...
override fun doWork(): Result {
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(Runnable {
        ... 
        val res = context.startActivity(intent)
        ...
    })
    return Result.success()
}
```

Call the expression outside a variable like;

```
context.startActivity(intent)
```

:)

Comment: Tried it but still the same, it works in emulators but not my real device (redmi note 8)

Comment: Try it on another device. Let's know if the problem is from yours.